# How to reset config files to default, especially boot sequence

Tags: etc

Is there a way to reset all ubuntu config files, a batch procedure?. No the local config files, I mean all /etc config files.

I know how to do that one by one but that is a job for weeks or work.

Comment: sort of off topic, but, for future sys admin. If I edit system files, I never delete the origional. I keep a copy in /root/etc. Furthermore, within the file, again never delete a line. Comment it out (usually a  `#`) , copy/modify/add line(s), and leave a comment as to why the file was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - there is no standard command.

But with the following command you may inspect which configurations may be different from the "default" configuration provided by the ubuntu packages.

```
 find /etc/ -name "*.dpkg-*"
```

Comment: wow, that will save a lot of work.